# Get request doesn't display value in HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, yahoo-weather-api

I think this is my stupidity and the problem is really slight but it just doesn't display anything after get request. I have no errors and I am getting return call 200. So everything in request seems to be fine.

```
if('geolocation' in navigator) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ 
  loadWeather(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
});
} else {
 loadWeather('Berlin, DE', '');
}

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
 $.simpleWeather ({
  location: location,
  woeid: woeid,
  unit: 'c',
  succes: function(weather) {
    city = weather.city;
    temp = weather.temp + '&deg;';
    wcode = '<img class="weathericon" src="assets/weatherimg' + weather.code + '.svg">';
    wind = '<p>' + weather.wind.speed + '</p><p>' + weather.units.speed + '<p>';
    humidity = weather.humidity + ' %';

    $('.location').text(city);
    $('.temperature').html(temp);
    $('.climate_bg').html(wcode);
    $('.windspeed').html(wind);
    $('.humidity').text(humidity);
  },

  error: function(error) {
    $('.error').html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
  }
 });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
 loadWeather();
});
```

This is my html code.

```
<section>
 <div class='mainContentHeader'>
  <h2> Weather App </h2>
 </div>
 <div class='mainContent'>
  <div class='container'>
   <p class='location'></p>
   <p class='temperature'></p>
  <div class='climate_bg'>
 </div>
 <div class='info_bg'>
  <img class='dropicon' src='/assets/Droplet.svg'>
  <p class='humidity'></p>
  <img class='windicon' src='/assets/Wind.svg'>
  <div class='windspeed'></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js'> </script>
```

Comment: if you put `console.log(weather)` in success what does it print?

Comment: Have you tried to parse the response before access it? I guess you are using JSON, try `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Because you misspelled `success`: `succes: function(weather)`, so your callback never gets called

Comment: eagle eyes lol @PatrickEvans

Comment: So that was my stupidity :) Thx @PatrickEvans